# Buttons require 2 taps on mobile - first tap is to trigger hover state. Second is to trigger onClick function

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a button in my React application. This button is working as intended on the web application, but when I open the app on my Iphone in Chrome, the button requires 2 taps to work. The first click is to trigger the hover effect, and the second is to trigger the onClick effect. I have 2 svg files - one for the hovered state and unhovered state. The svg image will render based on the isHover value.  Any help is appreciated!
Here are my codes:

```
const OptionsButton: FC<Props> = ({ 

    disabled=false, 
    className="options-button", 
    onClick, 
    style={cursor:'pointer',height:'34',width:'34',bottom:'15', right:'15',position:'absolute' } 

}) => {

    const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);

    const handleMouseEnter = () => {
        setIsHover(true);
    }
    const handleMouseLeave = () => {
        setIsHover(false);
    }
    const handleClick = (e : React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        onClick(e);
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    

    return (
        <>
        { 
            ( isHover )? 
            <OptionsBtnPr 
                className = {className}
                onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
                onClick={handleClick}
                style={style}
            /> :
            <OptionsBtn
                className = {className}
                onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} 
                onClick={handleClick}
                style={style}
            />
        }
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: You'll need to come up with a new interaction pattern for touch devices. There is no "mouse", so also no "mouse enter"/"exit" and no hover state. I suggest thinking about how you would expect the application to work if you had it on a phone.

Answer (score 0):

We should not need a hover state on mobile devices. For mobile devices we can always return `OptionsBtn`

Use `react-device-detect` library or any other method to have this `isMobile` check in place

```
import { isMobile } from 'react-device-detect';

    const OptionsButton: FC<Props> = ({
      disabled = false,
      className = "options-button",
      onClick,
      style = {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        height: '34',
        width: '34',
        bottom: '15',
        right: '15',
        position: 'absolute',
      },
    }) => {
      const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);
    
      const handleMouseEnter = () => {
        setIsHover(true);
      };
    
      const handleMouseLeave = () => {
        setIsHover(false);
      };
    
        
          const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement> | React.TouchEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
            onClick(e);
            e.stopPropagation();
          };
        
          return (
            <>
              {isHover && !isMobile ? (
                <OptionsBtnPr
                  className={className}
                  onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
                  onClick={handleClick}
                  style={style}
                />
              ) : (
                <OptionsBtn
                  className={className}
                  onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
                  onClick={handleClick}
                  style={style}
                />
              )}
            </>
          );
        };
```

If any issue still comes up then try passing the `onMouseEnter` prop to `OptionsBtn` only for `!isMobile`